# What does $f \in L^p(I,V) + L^q(I,H)$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

What does $f \in L^p(I,V) + L^q(I,H)$ mean? What does the addition mean?? I see this in PDE theory.

Comment: You should precise what are $I,V$ and $H$.

Comment: It means that $f$ can be written as the sum of a function in $L^p(I,V)$ and a function in $L^q(I,H)$. Although deviations are possible, the notation suggests that $L^p(I,V)$ and $L^q(I,H)$ are probably Bochner spaces.

Comment: @brom Your comment fully qualifies as an answer here. Please post as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $f$ can be written as the sum of a function in $L^p(I,V)$ and a function in $L^q(I,H)$. Although deviations are possible, the notation suggests that $L^p(I,V)$ and $L^q(I,H)$ are probably Bochner spaces.